# Subtype issues with generics in Kotlin

Tags: generics, overriding, kotlin

I have the following inheritance pattern in my code.

```
trait  A {
    fun foo(): Set<A>
}

trait B : A {
    override fun foo(): MutableSet<B>
}

trait C : A {
    override fun foo(): Set<C>

}

trait D : C, B {
    override fun foo(): MutableSet<D>
}
```

When B and D return Sets, the compiler is able to determine that `Set<D>` is a subtype of both `Set<B>` and `Set<C>`.  However, when I change the return types of `B.foo` and `D.foo` to `MutableSet`, the compiler is able to validate the return type of `B.foo` but I get an error reporting that the return type of `D.foo` is not a subtype of `MutableSet<B>`.

Why is Kotlin unable to infer this form of subtypes and are there any work arounds without overhauling my hierarchy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of an overriding function **must** be a subtype of the overridden one. In your example `MutableSet<D>` is not a subtype of `MutableSet<B>`. If it were, similar code could cause an exception at runtime:

```
trait B {
    fun foo(): MutableSet<B>
}

trait D : B {
    override fun foo(): MutableSet<D>

    fun onlyInD() {}
}

class BImpl : B {
    override fun foo() = null!!
}

class DImpl : D {
    private val set = java.util.HashSet<D>()

    override fun foo() = set
}    

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val impl = DImpl()
    // two variables pointing to the same instance
    val b: B = impl 
    val d: D = impl

    b.foo().add(BImpl())

    // ClassCastException on the next line: BImpl is not an instance of D
    d.foo().first().onlyInD()
}
```

See live example at [try.kotl.in](http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/104074971561017308771237608706/1040749715610173087711460272319)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I assume the reason that setting the return types to be `Set<B>` and `Set<D>` for B and D respectively does not yield an error is because the generic parameter to Sets is limited to being output types only?

Comment: Yes, if it wasn't covariant (out-only), it wouldn't compile